# Access data from express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am building an application in node.js.

I wrote a middleware function hook that executes whenever someone makes a GET request on my app, like if they go to the home page, profile page, etc. The hook makes a HTTP request from another API to collect data.

My question is how can I access that data on the client side? Here is my middleware hook:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = {
    authentication: function (req, res, next) {
       if (req.method === 'GET') { 
        console.log('This is a GET request');
         request("http://localhost:3000/api/employee", function(err, res, body) {
            console.log(res.body);
         });
       }
       next();
    }
};
```

It is used in all my routes:

`app.use(middleware.authentication)`

Sample route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('../views/home');
});
```

Notice I used `console.log(res.body)`, but I want to print the contents of that on the CLIENT side. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: how do you render a route? is the data returnd simple html you want to combine in the final html?

Comment: Hi - I updated my question to show a sample route. The data returned is simple HTML

Comment: could you add also a view and mark with a comment where you want the html in the root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set custom variables in `req` and `res` objects. Just like the code below which it is going to be stored on `req.my_data`. Later in your route, you can retrieve it from `req` again.

And, you need to call `next()` after you got the data, otherwise the code continues on before you get the data from `request`.

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = {
    authentication: function (req, res, next) {
       if (req.method === 'GET') { 
        console.log('This is a GET request');
         request("http://localhost:3000/api/employee", function(err, request_res, body) {
            req.my_data = request_res.body;
            next();
         });
       }

    }
};
```

And in your route, by passing the data to the template engine, you can have access that on the client side. Depending on your template engine (`ejs`, `jade` etc ...), the syntax vary.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('../views/home', {data: req.my_data});
});
```